# ¿Cómo ejecutar más de una vez una función JavaScript del lado del servidor en .NET?

Tags: asp.net

Estoy tratando de mostar un texto q vaya cambiando segun recorro un ciclo. pero solo toma el ultimo valor. Segun estuve leyendo que  `ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript` solo se ejecuta al final del bloque de código y necesito q cambie segun se itere el ciclo

```
int ValorTotal = 20;
for (int i = 0; i < ValorTotal; i++)
{
    var porcentaje = i * 100 / ValorTotal;
    ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Button2, GetType(), "Validador", "callprogress(90);", true);
}
```

Comment: Estoy tratando de mostar un texto q vaya cambiando segun recorro un ciclo. pero solo toma el ultimo valor. Segun estuve leyendo ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript solo se ejecuta al final del bloque de codigo y necesito q cambie segun se itere el ciclo

Comment: Entiendo que quieras sincronizar el porcentaje en lado cliente con la del servidor, pero **estás considerando mal el ciclo de vida de tu página ASP.NET**, la manera como expones tu pregunta **no** es posible debido a que intervienen otras tecnologías.

Comment: Hola Davlio, gracias por la respuesta. Tienes alguna dia de como se pudiera lograr algo asi o similar